# Trying to get all entity fields from a CRM record. C#

Tags: c#, attributes, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

Straight to the point, I am trying to make an application so that the user can search through their CRM system without going onto CRM. I have managed to retrieve the record but when i try to put the record into a list using the records attributes I am only recieving the Keys.

Here is the code:

```
 EntityCollection retrieved = _service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
        foreach (var c in retrieved.Entities)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<String, Object> attribute in c.Attributes)
            {
                lstRecordDetails.Items.Add(string.Format(attribute.Key + ": " + attribute.Value));
            }
        }
```

This only displays the recordID and the Record Name, I understand these are both the primary keys oh the record and i know i could use c.Attributes["description"] for the description but is there a way that i can get all the fields from the record and display them in the list?

Edit: Details on the query

```
        QueryByAttribute query = new QueryByAttribute(entity);
        query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(field);

        query.Attributes.AddRange(field);
        query.Values.AddRange(selected);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you can retrieve all the columns of an entity is

```
query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true);
```

However, be careful with this, because query all columns has an impact on the system (you should always retrieve explicitly the columns you need).

Answer (score 0):

```
RetrieveMultipleRequest retrieve = new RetrieveMultipleRequest();
retrieve.Query = query;
retrieve.ReturnDynamicEntities = true;

retrieved = (RetrieveMultipleResponse)Service.Execute(retrieve);

foreach(var dynEntity in retrieved.BusinessEntityCollection)
{
    foreach (var prop in dynEntity.Properties)
    {
        lstRecordDetails.Items.Add(string.Format("{0}:{1}", prop.Name, prop.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: c.Properties isnt a valid property?

Comment: Cannot convert type Entity to Dynamic Entity.

Comment: No how do i go about doing that?

Comment: QueryByAttribute doesnt contain a definition for ReturnDynamicEntities.

Comment: What reference holds ReturnDynamicEntities?

Comment: The CrmService web service; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb887829.aspx

Comment: this is CRM 4.0 code that it's not compatible with CRM 2011/2013